# Azure datafactory - pipeline, Dataset, container, linkservices

Tags: azure, dataset, pipeline, azure-data-factory

Does anyone know how I should configure the "Dataset" to read everything the Blob container has and to be able to perform the copy activity of each container?

I'm thinking of using a "GetMetada", but I don't know how to configure it since the "LinkServices" configuration leaves me inside the container and I get an error because in the "Dataset" I must configure the container and I don't know what to put there.

Comment: A blob storage Linked Service is to the account, not a specific container.You can configure a DataSet parameter for a variable container name - is that what you are asking?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you must understand is that Copy Activity is at least container-based. There is no one Copy Activity that can perform copy activities for all containers.

For reading everything in the container, just set like this:

[image]

(This can set all of the data in container 'test1' as source data.)

If you want to copy data from multiple containers, then you need multiple Copy Activities, like this:

[image]

Can my answer answer your question? Any doubts please let me know.:)